# TypeError: this.metadataScanner.getAllMethodNames is not a function in NestJS version 9

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices

I am using NestJS version 9 and trying to connect my apps through rabbitmq. However, I am getting the following error:

TypeError: this.metadataScanner.getAllMethodNames is not a function

from this line:
[image]

I have already upgraded to NestJS version 9 and installed @nestjs/microservices version 9.4.1. I suspect that a third-party package may be causing the issue.
here it is the nest info.

[image]

Can anyone suggest any troubleshooting steps or solutions to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: show us the output of `npx nest info`

Answer (score 0):

Common, core, microservices, platform-express, and testing should all be on the exact same version

Comment: as you see the nest info , it is

Comment: microservices at 9.4.1, the others I mentioned are at 9.3.1. Those are not **the exact same**

Comment: aw , i tested @nestjs/microservices 9.3.1 , unfortunately it doesn't work either :)

Comment: After installing `@nestjs/microservices` 9.3.1 did `nest info` reflect that?

Comment: Its so strange, in package json my @nestjs/microservices version is 9.3.1 , but in nest info is 9.4.2 !!

Comment: Is it `9.3.1` or is it `^9.3.1`? Other question, did you delete the `node_modules` and re-install?